# ActionDial does not display # in call screen

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem in this code, why does it not display # in call screen?

```
intent.button.Click += delegate {
   var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("tel:*177*1112223333#");
   var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionDial, uri);
   StartActivity (intent);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to encode (escape) the Uri to send a "#" to the dialer:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + Android.Net.Uri.Encode("*177*1112223333#"));
var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
StartActivity(intent);
```

[image]

Ref: [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966)

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `#` make use of `Android.Net.Uri.Encode("#")`.

```
intent.button.Click += delegate {
                var uri = Uri.Parse("tel:*177*1112223333" + Uri.Encode("#"));
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
```

---

You can also try replacing `#` with `%23`

```
intent.button.Click += delegate {
                var uri = Uri.Parse("tel:*177*1112223333%23");
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, uri);
                StartActivity(intent);
            };
```